geyser missing program id
when i used solders library there is
class CompiledInstruction:
    def __init__(self, program_id_index: int, data: bytes, accounts: bytes) -> None: ...
    def program_id(self, program_ids: Sequence[Pubkey]) -> Pubkey: ...
    @property
    def program_id_index(self) -> int: ...
    @property
    def accounts(self) -> bytes: ...
    @accounts.setter
    def accounts(self, accounts: Union[bytes, Sequence[int]]) -> None: ...
    @property
    def data(self) -> bytes: ...
    def __repr__(self) -> str: ...
    def __str__(self) -> str: ...
    def __richcmp__(self, other: "CompiledInstruction", op: int) -> bool: ...
    def __bytes__(self) -> bytes: ...
    @staticmethod
    def from_bytes(data: bytes) -> "CompiledInstruction": ...
    def to_json(self) -> str: ...
    @staticmethod
    def from_json(raw: str) -> "CompiledInstruction": ...

so i can import it from here like this
if instructions.program_id == Pubkey.from_string(raydium_v4_amm):

but with using geyser connection its missing from solana_storage_pb2.pyi file
class CompiledInstruction(_message.Message):
    __slots__ = ("program_id_index", "accounts", "data")
    PROGRAM_ID_INDEX_FIELD_NUMBER: _ClassVar[int]
    ACCOUNTS_FIELD_NUMBER: _ClassVar[int]
    DATA_FIELD_NUMBER: _ClassVar[int]
    program_id_index: int
    accounts: bytes
    data: bytes
    def __init__(self, program_id_index: _Optional[int] = ..., accounts: _Optional[bytes] = ..., data: _Optional[bytes] = ...) -> None: ...

i actually need to get these new mints filter from gRPC connection

